# Pairing 2 laptops via bluetooth and using one keyboard to control the other

Tags: keyboard, bluetooth

I'm using a Windows 7 laptop attached to my tv.  I have a wireless usb keyboard attached to it, however, I'd love to be able to control my laptop via another laptop via bluetooth. Is this possible? ie to pair 2 machines, and then type on one machine to another. The other laptop I'd like to connect from would either be a Macbook or a Toshiba Windows 7 machine.